# Does gdk_color_copy really allocate memory?

Tags: c, gtk, gdk

My impression from the [gdk docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/gdk2-Colormaps-and-Colors.html#gdk-color-copy) is that `gdk_color_copy` allocates memory:

> Makes a copy of a color structure. The result must be freed using
>   gdk_color_free().

The future-version `gdk_rgba_copy` clearly does:

> A newly allocated GdkRGBA, with the same contents as rgba

Nevertheless I am encountering memory errors in my code with the following (`my_struct.color` is a `GdkColor *`, initialized to NULL):

```
if (my_struct.color != NULL) {
    gdk_color_free(my_struct.color);
}   
my_struct.color = gdk_color_copy(color);
```

And the following appears to work:

```
if (my_struct.color == NULL) {
    my_struct.color = malloc(sizeof(GdkColor));
}   
memcpy(my_struct.color, color, sizeof(GdkColor));
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean with "memory errors"?

Comment: Corruption, or invalid pointer free, or other stuff on program exit.

Comment: Mhmm, I think I know what's wrong. I was calling g_free in my finalize method instead of gdk_color_free - swapping those seems to fix it? Really not sure that was possible

Comment: Yes, you must always match allocators. Mixing and matching results in bugs like these. You can see the source to see what `gdk_color_free()` really does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdk_color_copy` uses `g_slice_new` to allocate memory as can be seen in the [source.](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/gdk/gdkcolor.c#L126)

Using `g_free` instead of `gdk_color_free` or `g_slice_free` will cause errors. This can be verified by compiling with [G_SLICE=always-malloc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html#G_SLICE) which will cause `g_slice_new` to use malloc calls instead and the corruptions will disappear.